# Online LaTeX to vector image converter that actually works

Tags: latex

I would like to convert several LaTeX equations to a vector format (ai, svg, etc). I've spent hours searhing and testing. None of the sites that I found actually lets save a vector image. If you know an online LaTeX to vector image converter that works, please respond.

Comment: See [Convert LaTeX to SVG online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103282/5764), which also include the original source of the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is addressed here: [Convert LaTeX to SVG online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103282/5764). Two good answers are as follows:

To convert to SVG, you can try [Troy Henderson's LaTeX Previewer](http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/):

1. Type: <kbd>$$ E = mc^2 $$</kbd>
2. Click **Download**.
3. Select **SVG**.

Alternatively, you can use [CodeCogs LaTeX](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). It supports SVG format too.

1. Enter equation.
2. Choose `.svg` as format and options.
3. **Download** image.

Comment: Troy Henderson's LaTeX Previewer seems to work, except that the .svg file looks messed up in the Illustrator. But that's the Illustrator's fault :) CodeCogs LaTeX always loads a .gif even if I select .svg. Their forum page is broken.

Comment: CodeCogs is working for me in 2019